# Is it Possible to Meteor.call({}) using DDP connection in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, ddp

i want to access a data using remote connection using DDP connections,
i can subscribe data which is publish by remote connection but, i need to access more data from remote connection using Meteor.call()

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client) suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Never used this one but you may check this out

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddp_connect